# Detect any other app using the camera, while having the camera open in a service using old android API Camera

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, android-service, android-broadcast

I am using android's camera in a service grabbing data from onPreviewFrame. The moment another app opens using the camera, service's onPreviewFrame will constantly deliver the same data array (means it's somewhat freezing) until I restart camera.

Is there any way to detect the moment an app gets open which uses the camera as well (e.g. camera-app, snapchat etc.), except for a workaround (i.e. comparing the data arrays for duplicates)?

Please note: I am asking for old, deprecated android api "camera" - not camera2!

Comment: "The moment another app opens using the camera" -- another app can't open the camera. Your app has it open. Only one app can have the camera open at a time. `open()` on the other app should fail.

Comment: @CommonsWare It doesn't. I am using the camera in my app in a service, processing image data from OnPreviewFrame. While using the smartphone and opening any non-camera app works just fine, the moment I open e.g. Snapchat, "data" provided by OnPreviewFrame "freezes",  i.e. constantely returns the same raw picture data. This is probably due to me using the old camera API while apps like Snapchat might use a somewhat different API. 
However my question is simply whether there is a method to quickly detect apps using the camera.

Comment: "However my question is simply whether there is a method to quickly detect apps using the camera" -- none that I am aware of.